# Juntar contenidos de diccionarios en ficheros python diferentes

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, diccionarios

El problema que tengo es un poco rebuscado pero intentaré expresarlo lo más claro que pueda.

Tengo dos ficheros python que contienen diccionarios diferentes.

En el fichero `ciencia.py` el resultado del diccionario es el siguiente:

```
dict1 = { "microbiome": {
              "lang": "en",
              "lemmatizer": "microbiome",
              "Wikidata": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1330402"
              "DBpedia": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microbiota"
          }, ......
        }
```

EL contenido de la estructura de este diccionario se construye en una función que he llamado `process(palabra)`.

El resultado del fichero `compact.py` es el siguiente:

```
       dict2 = { http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microbiota :[
                        {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'ca'}, 
                        {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'en'}, 
                        {'keyword': 'Microbioma', 'language': 'es'}],
                 .... }
```

El contenido de la estructura de este diccionario se construye mediante una función llamada `query_kw(uri)` donde se hace una consulta a la página de DBpedia para coger las traducciones de la palabra de la uri. Este devuelve una lista con las diferentes traducciones de la palabra en forma de diccionarios.

Como se ve en `dict2`, este contiene traducciones de una palabra junto al idioma en el que se encuentran. Lo que pretendo hacer es comprobar si en `dict2` se encuentra la palabra de `dict1`.
En el pequeño ejemplo que he puesto anteriormente se puede ver. Si nos fijamos en `dict1` una clave del diccionario es "microbiome" entonces tengo que comprobar si esta se encuentra en la lista de diccionarios de `dict2`. Si no se encuentra como es el caso entonces añadirla a la lista de `dict2` de la misma forma que están las demás (`{'keyword': microbiome, 'language': 'en'}`).

Entonces el resultado tendría que ser el siguiente:

```
       dict2 = { http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microbiota :[
                        {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'ca'}, 
                        {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'en'}, 
                        {'keyword': 'Microbioma', 'language': 'es'},
                        {'keyword': 'microbiome', 'language': 'en'}],
                 .... }
```

Lo que he probado ha sido lo siguiente (se que no es nada óptimo pero era para tener una idea de como puedo hacerlo):

```
wrapper = query_kw(uri)
res_keys = process(palabra)
for k in rest_keys.keys():
    wrap = {'keyword': rest_keys[k], 'language': rest_keys[k]['language']
    for ind in wrapper:
        for key, value in wrapper[ind]:
            for ky, v in wrap:  
                if key is not ky and value is not v:
                    wrapper.append(wrap)
```

Ya digo, no es nada bonito de ver ni es nada óptimo y encima no funciona correctamente, pero no se me ocurre nada de cómo hacerlo. Espero haberme explicado bien.

Answer (score 0):

Pongo aquí la parte relevante del ejemplo, que es la manipulación de los datos de los diccionarios:

```
dict1 = {
    "microbiome": {
        "lang": "en",
        "lemmatizer": "microbiome",
        "Wikidata": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1330402",
        "DBpedia": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microbiota"
    }
}


dict2 = {
    "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microbiota" : [
        {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'ca'},
        {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'en'},
        {'keyword': 'Microbioma', 'language': 'es'}],
}

# ahora terms_by_url1 tiene la misma estructura que dict2
terms_by_url1 = {attributes["DBpedia"]: {"keyword": key, "language": attributes["lang"]} for key, attributes in dict1.items()}

# iteramos sobre todos los términos del primer diccionario, indexados
# por URL de DBpedia, y añadimos los que falten al segundo diccionario
for url, term in terms_by_url1.items():
    if term not in dict2[url]:
        dict2[url].append(term)
```